# Интерфейс базы данных

Tags: java, android, база-данных, архитектура

Есть база данных и много Фрагментов и Активностей, где ее нужно использовать. Можно ли отдельно создать или интерфейс или класс, где заранее создать методы, которые буду возвращать данные из БД?

Например, метод `getName` будет возвращать имя из таблицы. Просто не хочется в каждой активности писать кучу кода с `DBHelper`, `SQLDB` и `Cursor`.

Пробовал создать метод в главном классе, но при вызове в другом классе ничего не получается, выдает ошибку `NullPointerException`. У кого какие нибудь есть соображения?) Надеюсь доступно объяснил что хочу ....)

Answer (score 2):

таким образом у вас будет возможность использовать методы через экземпляр класса DbHelper

```
    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements IDbHelper {
    ****
     //нужно добавить реализацию методов описанных в интерфейсе
    }
```

---

```
public interface IDbHelper {
    void saveFavoriteRecipeId(int id, Context context);
    void deleteFavoriteRecipeId(int id);
    boolean recipeIsFavorite(int id);
}
```

Comment: А как например реализовать это: нужно получить значение из ячейки в таблице name ?

Comment: да это не очень хороший вариант тоже, ибо если вам необходимо в каком-то классе получить один Item, придется переопределить весь IDbHelper, разрастаться и рефакторить будет сложно

Comment: а как такое можно исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Данный метод далеко не является идеалом, но для решения вопроса и для будущего рефакторинга например в MVP, MMVI, будет очень удобен. Также будет в будущем удобен для организации в паттерн Repository и для DI в более сложных структур. Поэтому считайте что я продумал continuous implementation. Данный способ взят с официальных рекомендаций от Google:

Всё очень просто, мы создаем менеджер класс для работы с БД, причем как органзованна БД там не интересна это такой Helper. Мы делаем запрос getCar(), он дает нам item Car, но вся логика с таблицами и преобразованием происходит внутри этого класс. ПРимер:

```
/**
 * Singleton that controls access to the SQLiteDatabase instance
 * for this application.
 */

public class DatabaseManager {
    private static DatabaseManager sInstance;

public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseManager(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}

private DbHelper dbHelper;

private DatabaseManager(Context context) {
    DbHelper = new DbHelper (context);
}

public Cursor queryAllItems(String sortOrder) {
    //TODO: Implement the query
    return null;
}

public Cursor queryItemById(int id) {
    //TODO: Implement the query
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `ContentProvider` и вызывать `getContentResolver()` где необходимо.

Comment: Можно использовать Room

Answer (score 0):

Можно предложить использовать [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com), которая предлагает стандартную модель трансляции Java объектов в их SQL образы - [Object Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

В такой модели код получается достаточно удобным - [примеры здесь](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/), типа:

```
//получить DAO для работы с БД
RuntimeExceptionDao<MyData, Integer> myDao = getHelper().getMyDataDao();
//создать объект
MyData myData = new MyData();
//сохранить в БД
myDao.create(myData);
//получить список объектов из БД
List<MyData> myDatas=myDao.queryForAll(); 
//перебираем объекты
for(MyData myData:myDatas) {
   //blah-blah
}
```